# How to show a one column matrix with muilt-column

Tags: matlab, matrix

If a matrix just have single column,the matlab will waste many space to show it,like this

[image]

Of course,sometime the function `reshape` can help a lot.But when the number of element is a prime number,the `reshape` doesn't work anymore.If I'm in *Mathemtica* I can solve this problem like

[image]

Is there any elegant method for this question in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [sprintf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) you can print the array row-wise:

```
disp(sprintf([repmat('%d\t',1,4) '\n'], (1:17).'))
```

Result :

```
1       2       3       4
5       6       7       8
9       10      11      12
13      14      15      16
17
```

Comment: Elegant indeed.Thanks very much.If there is not better solution,I will accept it.

Comment: Just a little flaw I think,it will take up a character in the [new command line](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L9R5v.png)

Comment: @yode What about `disp(sprintf([repmat('%d\t',1,4) '\n'], (1:17).'))`

Comment: I think you should update it in your answer,that is a better solution.

Comment: Sorry,the question is solved,But could expand your method to *cell* object?In [this example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RgxUV.png),`t` have 17 element..

Comment: Try this: `disp(sprintf([repmat('%s\t',1,4) '\n'],t{:}))`